# Is there an option to generate scaffolding without generating migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

One of the things that bothers me in Rails is that scaffolding generates migrations that I don't always need.

Is there a way to generate the scaffold without the corresponding migration?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `--skip-migration` parameter. For example:

```
rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text --skip-migration
```

Comment: @tim-sullivan You know where I can find the documentation for the options pass to generators?

Comment: add `--help` to any command. For example, `rails generate scaffold --help`