# generate MVC from existing sql database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i would like to know if its possible to generate all mvc file from an existing database.
the reverse action of scaffold task.
please i really need the answer.
thanks.

Comment: You want this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907391/is-there-an-option-to-generate-scaffolding-without-generating-migrations ... Read that, try it, and reopen a new question with the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/ Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: yes its,i find what im looking for here: http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/
but there's a probleme, i cant run : rails magic_show -d mysql .
the console say: Command not recognized

Comment: well the "rails magic_show -d mysql" is just setting up a new Rails application. Try "rails --help" if that doesnt work are you sure that rails is set up in that directory?